# Alertbox and Action Sheet in swift 3

Tags: swift3, uialertview, uialertcontroller, uiactionsheet, uialertaction

I would like to choose the package type when I press on button. 

There are ***three types*** of package.
1. **Package A**
2. **Package B**
3. **Package C**

[image]

I have confused of how to implement this process. I don't know exactly it should be alert box or action sheet? 
 I'm not clearly understood this. Above image is action sheet, isn't it? 
But, I found that action sheet style has been deprecated in iOS 8 and later. So, I could not use this? 
Could you please explain me difference between Action sheet and Alert box in swift.?
  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Action sheets and Alert can be created with UIAlertController :
To create an Action Sheet you have to create an instance of UIAlertController and Adding actions to it : -

```
let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Package Type", message: nil , preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Package A", style: .default, handler: nil ))
actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Package B", style: .default, handler: nil ))
actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Package C", style: .default, handler: nil ))
actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel , handler: {
                (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                actionSheet.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }))
 present( actionSheet , animated:  true , completion:  nil)
```

You can replace the handler and replace with #selector as per your task .